# Scheduling airflow dag for 30 seconds

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am pretty new to airflow. I have a dag file which I'd like to schedule it for every 30 seconds. How can I do it?

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from dependency_node import DependencyNode, resolve_dependency_to_edges
import os

FILE_NAME = os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0]

default_args = {
  "owner": "airflow",
  "wait_for_downstream": True,
  "start_date": datetime(2019,12,19),
  "retries": 0
}

DAG_ARGS = {
  "schedule_interval": '*/1 * * * *',
  "catchup": False
}
```

This is how my dag arguments look like and it is scheduled for 1 minute but I want to schedule it to every 30sec.

I'd really appreciate if I can get some help

Comment: You can't unfortunately. Cron scheduling has a minute granularity and cannot be specified to the second.

Comment: Actually, you can. Add the same DAG again, perhaps with a `"start_date"` that is 30 seconds later. `datetime(2019,12,19,0,0,30)`

Answer (score 2):

Airflow 2 (I'm using 2.4.2) [supports timedelta for scheduling DAGs](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/scheduling-in-airflow) on a particular cadence (hourly, every 5 minutes, etc.) so you can put:

```
schedule_interval = timedelta(seconds=30)
```